# How to instantiate and rename a template class

Tags: c++

## Description

I declared a template class

```
template <typename T,size_t RootNum>
class Tree;
```

And  I want to specialize another template class BinaryTree, whose RootNum is 2, but every members is identicial with class Tree.
An inelegant method is defining a class BinaryTree inherits class Tree as below

```
template <typename T>
class BinaryTree: public Tree<T,2>{};
```

But I vaguely remember that it exists a declaration simillar to this style to 'elegantly' specialize a template class:

```
template <typename T>
typedef Tree<T,2> BinaryTree;
```

Actually the above code is invalid. I wonder is there a keyword-like to concisely achive this operation.

Thank you for your kind suggession.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for an alias template:

```
template <typename T>
using BinaryTree = Tree<T,2>;
```

Comment: Ah, I'm silly. I used to try 
```C++
template <typename T>
using BinaryTree<T> = Tree<T,2>
```
And I faild. I didn't realize it was like that.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Stackoverflow requires several minutes to allow you accept an answer